# Question About Xpub WRT jb55's Github Example

Tags: public-key, xpub, extended-fingerprint

First of, thanks for jb55's wonderful [tool](https://github.com/jb55/clightning-dumpkeys) for making dumping a c-lighting key easy. However, this is not the point of this post.
What i am here to ask is if you look at his example here:

> xprv9s21ZrQH143K2W9UqiTJL3qndXzRkEuzAoNwd6VLRu2VDtX6tACVz9q8BzDmJDkB6c6QQnfEWWvLtxB9M68XVpmcJCQodFrr843paWAXGeD   **root private**
> xpub661MyMwAqRbcEzDwwjzJhBnXBZpv9hdqY2JYRUtwzEZU6grFRhWkXx9c3HJ4EKR1Nvdwf5U3VoekstoKSKjfcJYhRrhMYeEzZzu2h7uZAQX **root public**
> xprv9wPk6zRy29x8BLXUHWh8ssqf89xQWtrZeLUgEXyUKSqNdUJhXTJsMtdLCexXxhgxPYUFpQvUhz2WAyhh3uCXSLedbHkvX7jTnX4xQofjdbA **extended private**
> combo(xprv9wPk6zRy29x8BLXUHWh8ssqf89xQWtrZeLUgEXyUKSqNdUJhXTJsMtdLCexXxhgxPYUFpQvUhz2WAyhh3uCXSLedbHkvX7jTnX4xQofjdbA/*)#u4tc9nwu   **extended private descriptor**
> xpub6AP6WVxrrXWRPpbwPYE9F1nPgBntvMaR1ZQH2vP5snNMWGdr4zd7ugwp3wukcTUxKu2rLCN9VBQAW3xioATnEWjZvQpx9cybj1jztJHJyp7 **extended public**
> combo(xpub6AP6WVxrrXWRPpbwPYE9F1nPgBntvMaR1ZQH2vP5snNMWGdr4zd7ugwp3wukcTUxKu2rLCN9VBQAW3xioATnEWjZvQpx9cybj1jztJHJyp7/*)#f64dm6yh   **extended public descriptor**

If you look really carefully, the actual extend private/public keys derived from the root (m/0/0) actually are different from what his example says.

Rather it should be:

> xprv9wT3HD7uDSkLA8WbJ7gVh57EJ3mmuVMesRTQSC8utJ3GCkCdp4LrbGFjrtW8vUjXEjL9tuC4uJpc33R6SYLxSx7qvRWgr7zf3pHxJupHzPG
> xpub6ASPgieo3pJdNcb4Q9DW4D3xr5cGJx5WEeP1EaYXSdaF5YXnMbf794aDiBTMaEXXB5tkQgdjgWCGN7g8BocDF8CnFYaiUdEnzJxznPUi8Vx

If you compare above with jb55's example after base58 decryption, you'll realize that everything is the same except the [parent fingerprint] in the two xpubs and of course the checksums. Despite the differences, they both produce the same addresses.

What could result such a difference in fingerprint happen? Does the author purposely do that? It can not be a mistake because the checksum there is just for preventing one.

Another question: will the difference in the [parent fingerprint] make any issues in the child generation?